# Measure the area of a polygon resulting from the intersection of two other polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, intersection

How can I measure the area of a polygon resulting from the intersection of two other polygons? If I use the measure tool or open the attribute table for the resulting polygon, it shows me the areas of the original two polygons...

Comment: Which program do you use?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Union tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000s000000.htm) to create a single featureclass from the two polygons and then [calculate the area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003q000000.htm) of each feature within the polygon.

Comment: you mean the "Intersect" tool instead of "union", right? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/

Comment: @jul Correct, but Union does the job too.  It also includes the remaining portions of the original polygons.

Comment: @jul Either will work, but like @whuber said, Union includes the remaining portions of the original polygons, which may be useful to @Jakub. Both will provide the required area, so it'll come down to the required application.

Comment: The crucial point is that @Romina may be using a GIS that does not automatically compute areas, even though it shows "Area" fields among the attributes.  Thus you need to calculate the new areas explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using ARCMap 10. I had been using ArcView 3.2 where I just did the intersection and could later read the area of the resulting polygon. I haven´t been able to do this in ArcMap yet...

Comment: Problem solved. I used the "calculate areas" as you sugested and worked. It's a little bit more annoying than doing it in arcview since I have to go through this additional step... Thanks!

Comment: The union tool works perfectly for I need to do as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Field Calculator to calculate area of new polygons that were split by the intersection, create a new field called Area, right click, choose Calculate Geometry. Choose what unit, and it will calculate the 2 new polygons correctly!